# Server side closed as soon as the client side is opened

Tags: java, server

Till now, my server-client application was working perfectly. Then suddenly when I decided to run it(first the server then the client), the server window closed after a second of opening the client window. Now, only the client window was left open. However, the javaw.exe processes (there are 2 of them, server and client) are not stopped. They are hooked to the port number I used in the game. Therefore, I get the JVM_Bind exception when run again.

I terminated both process and ran the application(s) again, but the same problem arises. I even changed the port numbers (on both the projects of course) but it gave me the same result.

The server and the client keep sending and receiving things automatically like in any multiplayer game.

Client side :

```
private void tick() {
    String info = handler.getPlayer(0).getX() + " " + handler.getPlayer(0).getY() + " " + handler.hb2.width + " " + handler.getPlayer(0).h1.x + " " + handler.getPlayer(0).h1.y + " " + handler.getPlayer(0).h2.x + " " + handler.getPlayer(0).h2.y + handler.getPlayer(0).h1.punch + " " + handler.getPlayer(0).h2.punch;
    sendMessage(info);
    String infoR = "";
    try {
        infoR = br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Scanner s = new Scanner(infoR);
    int a = 0;
    while(s.hasNext()) {
        String poop = s.next();
        a++;
        try {
            switch(a) {
            case 1:
                handler.getPlayer(1).x = Integer.parseInt(poop);
                break;
            case 2:
                handler.getPlayer(1).y  = Integer.parseInt(poop);
                break;
            case 3:
                handler.hb1.width = Integer.parseInt(poop);
                break;
            case 4:
                handler.getPlayer(1).h1.x = Integer.parseInt(poop);
                break;
            case 5:
                handler.getPlayer(1).h1.y = Integer.parseInt(poop);
                break;
            case 6:
                handler.getPlayer(1).h2.x = Integer.parseInt(poop);
                break;
            case 7:
                handler.getPlayer(1).h2.y = Integer.parseInt(poop);
                break;
            case 8:
                handler.getPlayer(1).h1.punch = Boolean.getBoolean(poop);
                break;
            case 9:
                handler.getPlayer(1).h2.punch = Boolean.getBoolean(poop);
                break;
            }
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            frame.setVisible(false);
            poop += " " + s.next(); 
            if(poop.equals("you lose")) new ResultDisplay("red");
            handler.hb1.resultDisplayed = true;
            stop();
        }
    }
    handler.tick();
}

public void sendMessage(String message) {
    pw.println(message);
    pw.flush();
}

private void init() {
    try {
        sock = new Socket("127.0.127.1", 1111);
        ostream = sock.getOutputStream();
        pw = new PrintWriter(ostream);
        istream = sock.getInputStream();;
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // more game initialization code follows
```

`init()` is called first and then the `tick()`method is called 60 times a second(ideally).

Server side:

```
    private void tick() {
    String info = handler.getPlayer(1).getX() + " " + handler.getPlayer(1).getY() + " " + handler.hb1.width + " " + handler.getPlayer(1).h1.x + " " + handler.getPlayer(1).h1.y + " " + handler.getPlayer(1).h2.x + " " + handler.getPlayer(1).h2.y + " " + handler.getPlayer(1).h1.punch + " " + handler.getPlayer(1).h2.punch;
    String infoR = "";
    try {
        infoR = br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Scanner s = new Scanner(infoR);
    int a = 0;
    while(s.hasNext()) {
        a++;
        String poop = s.next();
        try {
            switch(a) {
            case 1:
                handler.getPlayer(0).x = Integer.parseInt(poop);
                break;
            case 2:
                handler.getPlayer(0).y  = Integer.parseInt(poop);
                break;
            case 3:
                handler.hb2.width = Integer.parseInt(poop);
                break;
            case 4:
                handler.getPlayer(0).h1.x = Integer.parseInt(poop);
                break;
            case 5:
                handler.getPlayer(0).h1.y = Integer.parseInt(poop);
                break;
            case 6:
                handler.getPlayer(0).h2.x = Integer.parseInt(poop);
                break;
            case 7:
                handler.getPlayer(0).h2.y = Integer.parseInt(poop);
                break;
            case 8:
                handler.getPlayer(0).h1.punch = Boolean.getBoolean(poop);
                break;
            case 9:
                handler.getPlayer(0).h2.punch = Boolean.getBoolean(poop);
                break;
            }
        }catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            frame.setVisible(false);
            poop += " " + s.next(); 
            if(poop.equals("you lose")) new ResultDisplay("green");
            handler.hb2.resultDisplayed = true;
            stop();
        }
    }
    sendMessage(info);
    handler.tick();
}

public void sendMessage(String message) {
    pw.println(message);
    pw.flush();
}

private void init() {
    try {
        sersock = new ServerSocket(1111);
        sock = sersock.accept();
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
        pw = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // more game initialization code follows
```

The main game thread calls both the `init()` and `tick()` are called by the main game threads in both the projects

Comment: There is no way for us to answer without the code. And make sure it is a [mcve], rather than your full application, so that we can test it for ourselves.

Comment: I suppose that some exceptions must arise. So please log them and add them too the question. Some example code as mentioned in the  comment above would also be welcome.

Comment: Nope. No exceptions the first time and JVM bind exception the second time. I have added extra code

Comment: Still not enough code to diagnose: Who is calling `init()` in the server side?

Comment: Another suggestion: Do not run the server calling directly the JVM. Instead, run it from a command shell, so that the window never gets closed by the JVM.

Comment: a thread in both the projects calls them. It is my main game thread

Comment: @LittleSanti How does one do that?

Comment: Open a shell in your system (which is?), and type in `java -classpath ... <MyClass> <parameters...>`

Comment: @LittleSanti How does one open a shell? Windows 7 Ultimate x86 if that's what you were asking

Comment: @GhostCat I don't expect anyone to do the debugging for me, I was looking for suggestions with memory allocation and multiple threads running around. If you cannot help me, please do not impede my ability to get it from someone else. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your try and catch around the switch on your server you handle the exception by actually setting the visibility of your frame to `false` and you don't print out the exception, thus explains why you don't get an exception.

```
}catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    frame.setVisible(false); //<-- This bit
    poop += " " + s.next(); 
    if(poop.equals("you lose")) new ResultDisplay("green");
    handler.hb2.resultDisplayed = true;
    stop();
}
```

Of course you catch it for a reason, but maybe you should print out the exception it throws and not hide the frame? It could be throwing something you don't want it to throw.

Comment: Turns out, it was a problem with the message being received. Thanks!

Comment: @ARJAVGARG Am glad I could help. ^^